# Не могу вывести сообщение от друга хелп

Tags: python, django

Не выводит сообщения от друга мои отображаются друга нет. В базе данных и в админке комната есть и связь между друзьями , а вот вывести сообщения не получается. Не могу создать чат между друзьями. Тоесть сообщение отправленные мною другу выводятся , а вот сообщения от друга никак не получается вывести.

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.urls import reverse_lazy as _
from friends.models import Friend
from .models import Message, Room
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
User = get_user_model()
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
from django.db.models import Q
from django.urls import reverse_lazy


@login_required(login_url=_("accounts:login"))
def all_messages(request):
    # Output all messages
    friends = Friend.objects.friends(request.user)
    return render(request, "communications/all-messages.html", {'friends': friends})


@login_required(login_url=_("accounts:login"))
def chat_with_friend(request, friend_id):
    # Texting a friend
    friend = get_object_or_404(User, id=friend_id)
    room, created = Room.objects.get_or_create(author=request.user, friend=friend)

    if not Friend.objects.are_friends(request.user, friend):
        return redirect(reverse_lazy('communications:all-messages'))

    if request.method == 'POST':
        message_text = request.POST.get('message', '')
        if message_text:
            message = Message(room=room, author=request.user, friend=friend, message=message_text)
            message.save()

    messages = Message.objects.filter(Q(room=room), (Q(author=request.user) | Q(friend=friend)))

    friends = Friend.objects.friends(request.user)

    return render(request, 'communications/friend_messages.html', {'room': room, 'messages': messages, 'friends': friends})

from django.db import models
import uuid
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

User = get_user_model()


class Room(models.Model):
    # id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='author_room', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    friend = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='friend_room', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.id}-{self.author}-{self.friend}'
    

class Message(models.Model):
    room = models.ForeignKey(Room, related_name='messages', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='author_messages', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    friend = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='friend_messages', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    message = models.TextField()
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.message + " " + str(self.date)


{% extends "profiles/layout.html" %}
{% load static %}

{% block content %}
<main class="chat-with-friend">
    <h2>Чат с {{ room.friend }}</h2>
    <div id="chat-container">
        <ul>
            {% for message in messages %}
            {% if message.author == request.user %}
            <li>Вы: {{ message.message }}</li>
            {% else %}
            <li>{{ message.friend.username }}: {{ message.message }}</li>
            {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    </div>

    <form method="post" action="{% url 'communications:chat_with_friend' friend_id=room.friend.id %}">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <input type="text" name="message" id="message" placeholder="Введите сообщение">
        <button type="submit">Отправить</button>
    </form>

    {% include 'includes/scripts.html' %}
</main>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Не могу создать чат между друзьями. Тоесть сообщение отправленные мною другу выводятся , а вот сообщения от друга никак не получается вывести.

Comment: Напишите это в вопрос. Кнопка [edit].